# Why does the Alcubierre drive need a negative energy ring specifically?

Tags: spacetime, faster-than-light, warp-drives

Now, maybe this is a result of my poor understanding of spacetime, but a theoretical [warp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive) bubble contracts space in front, and expands it in the back. Positive energy always contracts, so I get the need for negative energy, but why or, more accurately, how is it supposed to work in the ring shape. Basically, I have 2 questions.

1. How is a ring of negative energy density supposed to generate a positive gravity well? It's not like a positive ring generates a negative one.
2. How does a ring even know where the 'front' is?

Comment: Like all impossible physical machines the Alcubierre drive starts with some form of unobtainium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a ring but a toroid (page 10), and it's the initial speed that determines the direction of the movement, see an article by  [the author](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20110015936/downloads/20110015936.pdf) of the idea.

The Alcubierre metric is a kind of Gullstrand-Painlevé metric.